# Return the first paragraph that doesn't include certain characters

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function, grep

I'm writing a custom WordPress excerpt function.

The first paragraphs of my posts start in various, but predictable, ways:

- Sometimes the first "paragraph" is a header (h3, h4)
- Sometimes it's a "byline" (*By John Smith*)
- Sometimes there's a header AND a byline
- And sometimes the first paragraph is the actual text of the article.

What I want to do is ignore the paragraphs that contain headers or bylines, and return a custom excerpt from the first "proper" paragraph.

There are thousands of entries so we're not going to add hand-crafted excerpts anytime soon.

I started going in the following direction, but I can't quite put my head around the logic I would use in this scenario. Also, I feel like there's probably a better (GREP?) way to do this.

Any suggestions?

```
function get_first_ctarticle_paragraph()
{
    global $post;
    $str = wpautop(get_the_content());


    //split content to first paragraph and the rest
    $paragraphs = explode('</p>', $str);

    //extract the first paragraph
    $first_paragraph = $paragraphs[0];
    $second_paragraph = $paragraphs[1];
    $third_paragraph = $paragraphs[2];
    if ((strpos($first_paragraph, '<h', 0) === false) && (strpos($first_paragraph, 'By', 0) === false) && (strpos($second_paragraph, 'By', 0) === false)) {
        echo wp_trim_words( $first_paragraph, 40, '...' );
    } elseif ((strpos($first_paragraph, '<h', 0) === false) && (strpos($first_paragraph, 'By', 0) === false) && (strpos($second_paragraph, 'By', 0) === false)) {
      // etc.
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample text, it's hard to be certain but it seems that just continuing your existing logic should work. Note that I would use a regex to match `By` to ensure it doesn't match something like `Bye Bye`:

```
if (strpos($first_paragraph, '<h', 0) === false && !preg_match('/\bBy\b/', $first_paragraph)) {
    // no header or byline in first paragraph
    echo wp_trim_words($first_paragraph, 40, '...' );
} 
elseif (strpos($second_paragraph, '<h', 0) === false && !preg_match('/\bBy\b/', $second_paragraph)) {
    // no header or byline in second paragraph
    echo wp_trim_words($second_paragraph, 40, '...' );
}
else {
    // header or byline in first and second paragraphs
    echo wp_trim_words($third_paragraph, 40, '...' );
}
```

If there were potentially more than 2 paragraphs at the beginning which could contain a header or byline, a loop would be more efficient:

```
$para = 0;
while (strpos($paragraphs[$para], '<h', 0) !== false || preg_match('/\bBy\b/', $paragraphs[$para])) {
    $para++;
}
echo wp_trim_words($paragraphs[$para], 40, '...' );
```

Comment: Thanks — that works, tho it was missing some parenthesis!

Comment: @Tomasch sorry about the typos, I've corrected them.